# Sorting taxons (Brands) alphabetically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Rails noob here trying to tweak a few things in a client's Spree shop.

The sidebar needs to contain a list of product brands, and I have Brands as a taxonomy.

My `shared/_taxonomies.html.erb` view contains:

```
  <% get_taxonomies.each do |taxonomy| %>
    <% if taxonomy.name == 'Brand' %>
      <h3 class='taxonomy-root'><%= t(:shop_by_taxonomy, :taxonomy => taxonomy.name.singularize) %></h3>
      <%= taxons_tree(taxonomy.root, @taxon, Spree::Config[:max_level_in_taxons_menu] || 1) %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

I added the `if taxonomy.name == 'Brand'` code to get rid of the categories. (I expect there's a cleaner way?)

How can I have the taxons (Brands) listed alphabetically?

Spree 0.70.3.

Answer (score 4):

It'd be much better to set

```
@brand_taxonomy = Taxonomy.where(:name => 'Brand').first
```

in a common controller, most likely `application_controller.rb` if the taxonomies are displayed on most/all pages, and then just go:

```
<h3 class='taxonomy-root'><%= t(:shop_by_taxonomy, :taxonomy => @brand_taxonomy.name.singularize) %></h3>
<%= taxons_tree(@brand_taxonomy.root, @taxon, Spree::Config[:max_level_in_taxons_menu] || 1) %>
```

thus eliminating the loop and conditional entirely.

Unfortunately the `taxons_tree` helper directly calls up the children of the top level taxonomy, so in order to get the children ordered by name, you'd have to rewrite the helper, say in `application_helpers.rb` as:

```
def my_taxons_tree(root_taxon, current_taxon, max_level = 1)
  return '' if max_level < 1 || root_taxon.children.empty?
  content_tag :ul, :class => 'taxons-list' do
    root_taxon.children.except(:order).order(:name).map do |taxon|
      css_class = (current_taxon && current_taxon.self_and_ancestors.include?(taxon)) ? 'current' : nil
      content_tag :li, :class => css_class do
       link_to(taxon.name, seo_url(taxon)) + 
       taxons_tree(taxon, current_taxon, max_level - 1) 
      end
    end.join("\n").html_safe
  end
end
```

The key change is the addition of `.except(:order).order(:name)` into the helper's children retrieval.

The final view code would look like:

```
<h3 class='taxonomy-root'><%= t(:shop_by_taxonomy, :taxonomy => @brand_taxonomy.name.singularize) %></h3>
<%= my_taxons_tree(@brand_taxonomy.root, @taxon, Spree::Config[:max_level_in_taxons_menu] || 1) %>
```

and in `application_controller.rb` you'd add:

```rb
before_filter :set_brand_taxonomy

def set_brand_taxonomy
  @brand_taxonomy = Taxonomy.where(:name => 'Brand').first
end
```

I have not implemented this in a Spree project myself, and it depends on you using a Rails 3.0.3+ version, but this is the basic approach I'd suggest.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. It doesn't seem to be quite working as it is. Due to an error about an undefined variable, I've added an `@` symbol to `my_taxons_tree(brand_taxonomy.root`. However, I then get `undefined method `root' for nil:NilClass` for this line. My application_controller.rb: http://pastie.org/3178498 (I removed the h3 line in the view as this also gave an error.)

Comment: Corrected for missing '@'; sorry about that.  So if you go: `rails console`

and then enter: `Taxonomy.where(:name => 'Brand')`

...what does it return?

It sounds like there is no parent Taxonomy named 'Brand'...?

Comment: Also, you added the `my_taxons_tree` helper method into `application_controller.rb`; I was recommending you put it into `application_helper.rb`, which is in `app/helpers` instead.  If you are certain you want to put it into application_controller, you'll want to add `helper_method :my_taxons_tree` to the top of the controller, and put it in a private block (just put a single line `private` before the `my_taxons_tree` definition.  It's more Rails-like to put it in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` though.

Comment: Corrected my placement (I misread). application_controller.rb: http://pastie.org/3183894 application_helper.rb: http://pastie.org/3183910 _taxonomies.html.erb: http://pastie.org/3183917 Rails console output: http://pastie.org/3183919 Error remains: `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Can you put  the full stack trace in a pastie?  That's a different error than the first one you mentioned.

Comment: `undefined method 'root' for nil:NilClass` from `<%= my_taxons_tree(@brand_taxonomy.root, @taxon, Spree::Config[:max_level_in_taxons_menu] || 1) %>` in the view. http://pastie.org/3185294 Thanks for your help.